# How can I set font-weight on parent tags of a specific tag when the tag has "required" attribute by using css?

Tags: jquery, css

Before asking the question, here is a sample code.

```
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <td><input type="text" required></td>
  <th>Age</th>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is to set `th` tag's html to be bold if the `input` tag under `td` tag has a `required` attribute.

I doubt that if it couldn't be possible since it has a condition. In that case, is there any way to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no previous sibling in CSS , it is not possible using CSS
Check this link for more details - [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Loop all input fields inside td tag using **$('td input')**
2. Use **.each** method to loop through all input fields inside **td** tag
3. Check for the attribute required
4. If found, get parent element of input **i.e td** and previous element of td **i.e th** and apply css- **font-weight**

```js
    $('td input').each(function(i){
      console.log(i)
      if($(this).attr("required")=='required'){
        console.log($(this).parent().prev())
         $(this).parent().prev().css('font-weight', 'bold')
      }
    })
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZoEVYN

**Note**- font-weight of th is bold by default, just for difference, i made **th** tag font-weight as normal in codepen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('input:required').parent().prev().addClass("required");` to add a class required to all headers of required inputs, then use that class in css to bold it. If I am not mistaken, css selectors cannot select previous elements, so there is not a pure css solution.

```js
$('input:required').parent().prev().addClass("required");
```

```css
th {
  font-weight: normal;
}

th.required {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" required></td>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no previous sibling nor parent selector in CSS.
However, there is a next sibling selector, which makes it possible to implement a minimal, elegant and less error prone solution using this one-liner:

```
$("th ~ td>input:required").parent().prev().addClass("required");
```

The beauty (and **addition to previous answers**) is that this selector **ONLY** selects input tags if they:

- are marked as *required*

**AND**

- are located inside a *td* tag with a preceding *th* sibling

...thus eliminating the risk of `parent().prev()` failing for tables with a different structure.

Here is a code pen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqWoJr